# Unitary test for a gzip compression function?

Tags: function, testing, gzip

Given an implementation of the gzip specification, how to test if it is compressing accordingly to the specification, i.e. a valid gzip file?

My unitary test compresses an input and then decompresses it, comparing the input with decompressed output. I dont think that is sufficient to guarantee it is satisfying the specification.

Anyone know a valid strategy to test a gzip compression function?

Comment: Compare output against another, known good, implementation.

Comment: Can you precompute the checksum and then test whether the compressed test file's checksum and precomputed value match

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I thought about that, but if the other implementation has flaws then my test isnt good (I know you said 'known good' but Im looking for something that doesnt rely in another implementation)

Comment: @dmd_anfini: You don't really have any option.  Your reference has to come from somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use [zlib](http://zlib.net/)'s inflate to test the output.  inflate is very careful to reject invalid deflate data, for security reasons.

Note however that that will only test the streams you run through it.  You'll need to craft many tests to make sure that you exercise all of the possible sorts of output that your deflator can produce.

Comment: I was thinking about testing the file format according to the specification, but since zlib implementation was done by the creators of the format, I guess its ok to rely on it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could test your implementation against another implementation, e.g. the command line `gzip` tool:

- compress some data with your implementation, then decompress the result with `gunzip` and compare with the original
- and vice-versa, compress some data with `gzip`, then decompress with your implementation and compare